# What should I upgrade first – CPU or GPU?

Tags: cpu, gpu, computer-building

I have an HP desktop for gaming and I wanted to upgrade it to suit games like GTA V, Witcher 3, Fallout 4, and games like that.

My specs:

- AMD A6 6400k
- AMD R7 240 2GB VRAM
- 8GB RAM
- 1TB HDD
- 60 Hz 1680×1050 Monitor
- (no SSD)

I get 20 fps in GTA V on very high settings and my budget is very tight. I can only upgrade one part right now and will have to wait a year for another – so what should I upgrade now? I am ready to spend 300-500 dollars. Changing the CPU requires a new motherboard, but the CPU is very weak. I am not familiar with building computers – should I buy a new pre-built computer altogether?

Comment: A CPU upgrade would require a new motherboard/memory but your current CPU isn't going to run any of those games and you have nearly no upgrade options with your current socket

Answer (score 0):

While playing a game, the heavy lifting is done by the graphics card, I would upgrade this component first to improve gaming experience. As long as the new card is compatible with your system and up-to-date you are on the right track, if the result does not satisfy you can then also upgrade the rest of your system (CPU,RAM,Mainboard) next year. If you are into gaming an investment into a new powerful graphics card is what you need anyways. I also believe your budget sounds reasonable for a graphics card but a bit optimistic for a new package of CPU, RAM and Mainboard.

Comment: I agree. If you can only upgrade one part, go with the best graphics card you can afford (GTX 1070, perhaps?), which will definitely improve your experience. Plus, the card can be moved to a newer system if you upgrade in the future.